# AdMob AdSize FLUID not matching parent's width

Tags: android, admob

I want to load AdMob ads in a `RecyclerView`. What I'm trying to accomplish is giving the ad the same width as the other items in the `RecyclerView` while maintaining the right aspect ratio.

In the AdMob [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize) I found the following explanation for what AdSize FLUID should do:

> A dynamically sized banner that matches its parent's width and expands/contracts its height to match the ad's content after loading completes.

ViewHolder xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/admob_viewholder"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/card_margin_left"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/card_margin_right">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="300:250"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#0f0"
            app:adSize="FLUID"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

I was expecting to get an MEDIUM_RECTANGLE because of the 300:250 aspect ratio. Why am I not getting a MEDIUM_RECTANGLE and why is the banner not at least matching it's parent's width like it says in the documentation?

Edit: I know about the SMART_BANNER which is based on screen width, but I'm asking about the FLUID size because it's documentation says it's based on the size of the parent's view which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

replace your adview code this

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0f0"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />
```

Comment: I know about the SMART_BANNER AdSize and that works fine. I'm asking specifically about the FLUID AdSize because if it would behave like the documentation says it should it would better suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `app:adSize="FLUID"` Replace it with `app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"`

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#0f0"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />
```

refer this for different adSize:-https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Comment: I know about the SMART_BANNER AdSize and that works fine. I'm asking specifically about the FLUID AdSize because if it would behave like the documentation says it should it would better suit my needs. BTW, my question is based on the information found at the page you linked.